# How to access JSON object element when the name of the element is a date?

Tags: javascript, json

I am developing a profit and loss tracker for an MMO, it uses the games API to get data about certain items in the games economy.

It returns this data as a JSON object, I am attempting to use this data to populate graphs in future. I'm struggling to access each element of the object. The data returned looks like so:

```
 daily: {2020-05-19T00:00:00.000Z: 794, 2020-05-20T00:00:00.000Z: 823, ... ETC
```

I need to access each element, then use its name and value to populate the graph, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: That's not a JSON

Comment: Assuming it's really `{"2020-05-19T00:00:00.000Z": ...}`, then once it's parsed to actual JS you can use the key name as usual, `obj["2020-05-19T00:00:00.000Z"]`.

Comment: `Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) { /* do something with data[key] */ })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to access each element, then use its name and value to populate the graph

You can do that in many ways, such as:

```
for (let key of Object.Keys(yourObject)){
    let value = yourObject[key];
    //use both key and value as you please
}
```

If you need to access a specific property with a key like you have shown, you can do it with:

```
let value = yourObject["2020-05-19T00:00:00.000Z"];
```

Comment: I want to try and do something like `yourObject.daily.map(dateNames)` and then `yourObject.daily.map(values)`, saving them to arrays and then using those arrays to display the data, do you know if this is possible?

Comment: @Marmiton You want to "convert" the object to an array ? You can do that with the for loop i showed. just inside it use `myArray.push(yourObject[key])`  which gives you an array with the values. If you push the key only with get an array with the keys, even though thats unnecessary because `Object.keys` already gives you an array with the keys. If it is something else you're looking for you're going to have to be more specific.